# ¿Cómo abrir el puerto 443?

Tags: puertos, iptables

En el servidor se instaló iptables-services y se agregaron varias reglas para abrir el puerto 443, pero aun así no se abre.

Esto tiene el archivo /etc/sysconfig/iptables con política `ACCEPT`:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

al revisar iptables `iptables -L -n`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:443 state ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:443 state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
```

Claro, tiene más cosas, pero entiendo que con eso ya debe estar activo el puerto 433. Pero al hacer `nmap <sitio>` obtengo el siguiente mensaje:

```
443/tcp  closed https
```

Entonces, ¿cuál es el problema? Los puertos 80, 22, etc. funcionan con normalidad, pero el 443 para https no se abre. ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Fíjate que tu política por defecto es aceptar todas las conexiones entrantes y salientes. Por lo tanto, tienes todos los puertos abiertos, y el firewall no está actuando.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no tenia el servicio activo: mod_ssl